# Run multiple php script using Ajax button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to run multiple php script based on different button clicks.
When use clicks on the button, I don't want page to reload, just basically run the php script.

Here is my code but for some reason I can't get following code to get working.

I think I am not calling button ID correctly.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Example</title>


    <script>


    $('.myButton').click(function() {

     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "run.php"
    }).done(function( resp ) {
      alert( "Hello! " + resp );
    });    

    });

    $('.myButton2').click(function() {

     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "run1.php"
    }).done(function( resp ) {
      alert( "Hello! " + resp );
    });    

    });

    $('.myButton3').click(function() {

     $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "run2.php"
    }).done(function( resp ) {
      alert( "Hello! " + resp );
    });    

    });



    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton" />
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton2" />
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton3" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there's no php here, so why the tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myButtonx')
```

will get element by class name and I don't see any such class added to the buttons.

use `$('#myButton1'), $('#myButton2'), $('#myButton3')` where you've used `$('.myButton1')$('.myButton2')$('.myButton3')` and this should work

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are not calling the buttons correctly.

```
$('.button') // Calling a button with the button class
$('#myButton3') // Calling a button with the button id
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. You are calling click event using classes but none of that class exist, so i changed code to use Ids.
2. Its a good approach you call these type of event on `document.ready()`
3. Always use javascript at the end of the page, it will decrease page loading time.

Here is the working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Example</title>


    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton" />
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton2" />
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="myButton3" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>


    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#myButton').click(function() {

         $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "run.php"
        }).done(function( resp ) {
          alert( "Hello! " + resp );
        });    

        });

        $('#myButton2').click(function() {

         $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "run1.php"
        }).done(function( resp ) {
          alert( "Hello! " + resp );
        });    

        });

        $('#myButton3').click(function() {

         $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "run2.php"
        }).done(function( resp ) {
          alert( "Hello! " + resp );
        });    

        });
    });



    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working my friend, is this the correct approach?

Comment: Yes i ran this on my machine

Comment: What exactly not working on you machine? Can you please check in Developers tools if its sending the ajax request?